# What is the correct way to perform a 301 redirect in .htaccess for URLs with a parameter?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to do a simple 301 direct on some old URLs that have parameters to them.

e.g.

```
redirect 301 /display.php?id=2 http://www.url.com.au/about/
redirect 301 /display.php?id=4 http://www.url.com.au/news/
```

My experience with .htaccess is limited. What would be the simplest and the most correct way to enable the above redirects to actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work given that you don't have other rules that may interfere with this one:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
RewriteRule ^display.php$ /about/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=4$
RewriteRule ^display.php$ /news/ [R=301,L]
```

If the domain is not the same domain then you may include the full qualified domain as in:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=2$
RewriteRule ^display.php$ http://www.url.com.au/about/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! Definitely is very much appreciated.